# HTTPS (TLS/SSL) server on Nitrous.IO

Tags: ssl, https, nitrousio

May I ask how to create TLS server on Nitrous.IO Boxes?
I think what I have to get for that at least are cert.pem and key.pem or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what region you are in, you can get SSL authentication automatically.  Will that suffice?

http://help.nitrous.io/ssl/

Answer (score 0):

For me, https works out of the box.

I set my server to listen on port 3000, configured the Nitrous preview port to 3000, and then I can get access via:

- http://silly-name-121212.nitrousapp.com:3000/
- http://silly-name-121212.nitrousapp.com/
- https://silly-name-121212.nitrousapp.com/

(This URL is just for illustration; your URL will differ.)

Within the application itself, you can `X-Forwarded-Proto` request header will tell you if the request was http or https.