# SSL/HTTPS on nitrous

Tags: node.js, ssl, nitrousio

Is it possible to run a dev https server on nitrous?

Basically, I'm attempting to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871565/how-to-create-pem-files-for-https-web-server?rq=1) on a nitrous box, and while the server seems to run, requests time out and are not received. According to nitrous docs, port 443 is not allowed?

After some further research - essentially I'm trying to do exactly what is described [here](http://chrislarson.me/blog/ssl-nodejs-express-and-socketio). So I think the question really is does Nitrous allow for custom port forwarding? Is there anyway to forward 443, where https requests come in, to some port in the allowed range?

Comment: Duplicate question, but does not have any answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853700/https-tls-ssl-server-on-nitrous-io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL is supported if you upgrade to a paid plan, but only if your box is within either the U.S. region or the Europe region. https://www.nitrous.io/pricing

You can also run a HTTPS server by deploying your application to a production platform such as Heroku, Cloud66 or Nodejitsu, where SSL is not blocked.

http://help.nitrous.io/categories/deployment/

According to "[Does Nitrous.io allow port 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564735/does-nitrous-io-allow-port-80)," port 443 is not allowed, and there is no way to set custom port forwarding as only Nitrous has control over that (if I recall correctly, they are using Nginx to control Nitrous.io boxes on Amazon EC2 instances).

This means that not only Nitrous does not provide an SSL service for HTTPS connections outside the U.S. and European regions (for now), you're out of luck in choosing a third party solution.

Remember that Nitrous is designed to be used for development purposes, not for production.

Comment: See clarification above - the question is not whether nitrous itself provides ssl services but rather whether one can setup SSL in dev.